# Table storage engine for 'table_name' doesn't have that option

Tags: mysql, magento

I recently setup apache,mysql,phpmyadmin etc on my OSX Mavericks 10.9.3
Now i am trying to import a database by terminal and i get this error message : `Table storage engine for 'table_name' doesn't have that option`
I had no problem before on another Mavericks macbook, only differences is that sql version in this is 5.7.9 and on the old is 5.5.34 
I am trying since 2 days non-stop to solve this issue, db has not problem, i did manage to import ok on the old machine.
Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try define a default storage engine for you table 
in you mysqlimport utlity

```
 --default-storage-engine=<def_engine>
```

see this [doc for reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldbimport.html)

Comment: I use normal method as always mysql -u [username] -p [database_name] < [dumpfilename.sql] , strange is that in this new machine i just uploaded a smaller database without any errors. i cannot add  --default-storage-engine=<def_engine> in this command line. any suggestions?something changed in mysql newer version?i'm really lost here

Comment: I presume you can specify parameter for import. What utility you use for import?

Comment: I am using import via terminal with the command i wrote above. I have more news, very strange. I had to remove 1 table and the database was imported ok. Then i tried to manually sql and create this table but no possible. problem was that i had to remove at the end "ROW_FORMAT=FIXED COMMENT='Catalog Product Relation Table';" Does this make any sense?Something i need to change when i setup mysql on the new machine?Never had problems like this and as i mention also same database import with no problems on another machine (oldest mysql version) thanks

Comment: running `sed -i 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED//g' file.sql` worked for me although i have not yet found the downside of it